# Javascript window.innerHeight and random numbers

Tags: javascript, random, window

In the js code below, the variable `left` gives a random number up to the size of the browser's inner window width. But the same code applied to `window.innerHeight` will write "[object Window]", though it does write a numeric value for `iH`.

Why? 
Is there a way to successfully accomplish this?
Thanks!

```
var iW = window.innerWidth;
document.write(iW+'<br>');
var iH = window.innerHeight;
document.write(iH+'<br>');

var left = Math.floor(Math.random()*iW);
document.write(left+"<br>");
var top = Math.floor(Math.random()*iH);
document.write(top+"<br>");
```

Comment: Browsers already define a global [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.top). Try giving it another name or use it inside a `function`.

Comment: gotcha. that's the answer.